# Unit testing service method in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mockito, rx-java, junit5

I have been doing unit testing with JUnit 5 and Mockito for the following code that I am going to show you, but it is not working correctly. I want to evaluate the successful case.

```
public Maybe < MyResponse> generate(String numberValue) {
  return Maybe.just(numberValue)
        .filter(number -> number.length() == Constants.REQUEST_REQUIRED) //R_R = 16
        .flatMap(number -> MyUtils.generate())
        .map(MyMapper::createResponse)
        .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.error(MyExceptioManager.throwException400(...)));
}
```

I tried converting the static methods to instance methods and then invoked them with @Mock, but it didn't work. How can I do this?

I did this:

```
@Test
void generate() {
    String numberValue = "1234567891234567";
    // when(myUtils.generate()).thenReturn(any()); 
    when(numberValue.length()).thenReturn(eq(16));
    when(myMapper.createResponse(anyString())).thenReturn(any(MyResponse.class));

    myService.generate(numberValue )
             .test()
             .assertNoErrors()
             .assertComplete()
             .assertValue(myResponse -> myResponse.getCode().equals("1234"));
}
```

error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
>     when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Comment: what is the error you are facing ?

Comment: @RyuzakiL , I just put it in the post.

Comment: you should not mock this `when(numberValue.length()).thenReturn(eq(16));` pass `numberValue` as real value to `generate` method

Comment: What is Mock buying you here?  I don't get it.  Pass the parameter and call the real thing.

Comment: I was doing tests but when I remove it and pass the real parameter, I get this error in the same way: `NullPointerExcepcion: exception is null`

Answer (score 0):

you can mock a static method in a static class through the below code:

```
...
try (MockedStatic<MyUtils> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(MyUtils.class)) {
        utilities.when(MyUtils::generate).thenReturn(...what your method should return...);
        //test your target method like:
        myService.generate(numberValue);
    }
```

reference: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods